# Can't touch UIButton behind UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` behind a `UIScrollview`, and i want to be able to touch the button. Has it's obvious at this moment i can only perform actions on the `UIScrollview`, but i also want to be able to perform actions on the `UIButton`

Comment: Its impossible. your button is covered by scrollview. Until scrollview appears on top of the button, you cant click on button

Comment: @BharathVankireddy nothing is impossible.

Comment: Don't worry brother, lets try by your own and post the solution here, even I will be happy by seeing that.

Comment: try -- `scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
-- But then you wont be able to interact with the scroll view.

Comment: You can use the bringSubviewToFront property of the button and scrollview Superview in  order to make the button on the scrollView
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:

Comment: Why not put the button on top of the `UIScrollView` instead of behind it?  If you do that, it should work fine without any hackery.  If it's behind the scroll view, how would the user be able to see it in order to know they could interact with it?

Comment: If you only concern about to call an action attached to that button then you can do it manually as well. `[self methodName:sender];` but this want let your user touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "*nothing is impossible*" ... Sure, but it might be insanity.

---

If you want the `UIScrollView` to remain touchable to the user, you could try something similar to what [Hemang suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877012/cant-touch-uibutton-behind-uiscrollview/34877904#comment57494702_34877012).

I would suggest sending the a signal to the `UIButton`'s `touchUpInside` event directly through. For example, in your `UIViewController`:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture;

    UIButton* button;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){30, 30, 300, 300}];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){20, 20, 300, 500}];
    tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewWasTouched)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


}

-(void) buttonPress {
    NSLog(@"Button press!");
}

-(void) scrollViewWasTouched {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, [tapGesture locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view])) {
        [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

@end
```

I have no idea why you would **ever** want to do this though!

---

### EDIT

I now learn that you want to do this as you want images in the scroll view to behave like buttons. I would suggest you simply replace your `UIImageView` objects with `UIButton` objects.

You can then just add the image to the `UIButton` directly:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I'm using a uiscrollview to scroll thought images, and i have a button to perform an action when i touch an image.

Comment: This could work, but i don't want to perform an action when i drag the uiscrollview. This way that will happen.

Comment: My answer won't perform the button action when you scroll. It only performs when you tap. However, have you considered simply adding a `UITapGestureRecogniser` to the `UIImageView` directly? or overlaying the `UIButton` over the `UIImageView`? **OR** better yet, replace the `UIImageView` with a `UIButton` and add the image to the button directly. I think there are a number of solutions that aren't as hacky as what you're asking for.

Comment: those are good solutions, it's just one of those days were i should just take a break a come to the office the next day.

Comment: This seems to allow the method to trigger for the button, however the user still cannot actually tap the button and thus you don't get any UI feedback (such as highlighting of the button) that you've tapped it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override method

`override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?`

in superview of scrollView and Button. This method should return receiver for specific point. So in your case it should be something like that

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? { 
if CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point) {
return button
}
return super.hitTest(post, withEvent: event)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how does the UIScrollowView class know about the button if the button is from a viewController?